# On perfect HTML, WebDriver gives a NoSuchElementException on the controls

Tags: testing, selenium, functional-programming, automation, webdriver

I was trying to automate the Reset functionality in "http://www.efrotech.com/careers" for learning purposes. When I get the control locators I see it is perfect HTML that has almost all the locators; but when I try to run the script it is not recognizing the control and throwing painful `NoSuchElement` exception. Can you suggest what could be going wrong in that?

```
    package com;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class ScriptChecker {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static String baseUrl;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        baseUrl = "http://www.efrotech.com";


        driver.get(baseUrl +"/careers");


        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddlJobs"))).selectByVisibleText("QA Engineer");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#txtName")).sendKeys("Muzaffar");

        System.out.println("Done here");

    }

}
```

I have tried every locator but unable to manipulate the control state and its values.

***Stacktrace followed:***

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ddlJobs"}
Command duration or timeout: 10.07 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'muzaffar', ip: '192.168.0.161', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_05'
Session ID: 206431fe-6770-4cbc-a60e-71fe92739807
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=25.0.1, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at com.ScriptChecker.main(ScriptChecker.java:30)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ddlJobs"}
Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:17:32'
System info: host: 'muzaffar', ip: '192.168.0.161', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_05'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at .FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_(file:///C:/Users/SMUZAF~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1906408348495286600webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8905)
    at .fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/SMUZAF~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous1906408348495286600webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:396)

Comment: What line is the failure at?

Comment: Failure is at Identifying controls, e.g. with "ddlJobs", "txtName" and all others on the form, says NoSuchElementPresent whereas element do exist and have IDs, CSSelectors, Xpath etc etc. eventhough showing NSEException.

Comment: okay - and I guess since you suspected the element is not visible, you added the `WebDriverWait` with `visibilityOfElementLocated`?

Comment: It was added because of the fact that Internet might be slow in laoding the pag.

Comment: Agreed - good thought. Can you also try inserting a simple `Thread.sleep(5000)` before the `findElement(ddlJobs)`? (This is not a permanent solution obviously)

Comment: Its of no use since I can handle the timing from driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); this line 10 20 30 seconds etc.

Comment: ImplicitWait is different - I am asking you to *force a sleep*. In my experience, a lot of basic NoSuchElement problems with Selenium have come down to timing.

Comment: Right, but it was actually not working as well.

Comment: @Louis: question is updated, added class code and stack trace.

Comment: @Nitin: same exception thrown for IFrame locator as well.

Comment: @Nitin: Thanks a lot, I actually misplaced the IFrame locator line. After placing to the position you've suggested it has been doing what I was trying. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop down element which you are trying to use is under iFrames. Please switch to it and then proceed with your selection.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[height='520']")));
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddlJobs']"))).selectByVisibleText("QA Engineer");
```

hope this solves.

Comment: Can you suggest me way how can I find the cssLocator from Firepath, Firebug or any other tools? When put this "iframe[height='520']" in firepath it evaluates to nothing.

Comment: this won't work if you give it directly in firepath. You can see that select box is under a different block. If you are using iframes without "id" attribute. You can search with "cssSelector". There are multiple iframes in your page. To locate this particular one, you need to differentiate with others by using attributes attached to it. So i suggested going with height attribute.